# DataGridView not showing base class properties

Tags: c#

Person class

```
class Person
{
  public string name;
  public int age;

 public Person() {}

 public Person(string pName, int pAge)
 {
   name = pName;
   age = pAge;
 }
}
```

Member class

```
class Member:Person
{
  private string _email;

  public string Email
  {
    get{return _email;}
    set{_email = value;}
  }

 public Member(){}

 public Member(string pName, int pAge, string email): base(pName, pAge)
 {
   Email = email;
  }
}
```

I want to display all properties in the DataGridView but when I click the display button only the email shows up in the DataGridView.

Comment: Try changing name and age to properties.

Comment: @Nick Thank you now it's showing !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing name and age to properties.

Only public properties are shown automatically by DataGridView.